# regex python или цикл?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Задача такая необходимо сделать regex что бы он  удалял все комбинации '[1]' и  перед ним стоящий символ с оговоркой, если он встречает комбинацию из символов  '[2]' то  regex  должен удалить только комбинацию  '[1]',  а перед ним стоящий  символ не трогать.
В моей реализации работает удаление '[1]' только 1 раз , как заставить regex  удалить все  комбинации '[1]' и перед ним стоящий символ во всей строке.

Это все таки необходимо сделать через цикл те убирать все комбинации в несколько проходов или можно обойтись одним regex?

Например такая строка  **"истинный сии[2]ии[1][1][1]мвол"** на первом проходе убрали  **"истинный сии[2]и[1][1]мвол"** на втором убрали  **"истинный сии[2][1]мвол"** и тд ...

```
import re

str = "Если здоровье  [2][1] — истинный сии[2]ии[1][1][1]мвол с[1]вободы, тоooo[1][1][1] спорт — истинный симвв[1]оo[1]л здоровья"
str = re.sub(r'[^\[2\]].?\[1\]', '', str)
```

Comment: цель удалить все комбинации [1] и + 1 символ перед ним стоящий  но если попадается [2] то удалить только комбинацию [1]. в вашем примере он удалит только [1]

Comment: если просто удалить, то он удалить только комбинацию [1] , а по заданию, если попадется такая комбинация надо удалить ее и впереди стоящий символ.  В Вашем первом примере он удаляет только  комбинацию, но не как впереди стоящий символ, что не соответствует условию задания

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```
import re

text = "Если здоровье  [2][1] — истинный сии[2]ии[1][1][1]мвол с[1]вободы, тоooo[1][1][1] спорт — истинный симвв[1]оo[1]л здоровья"

def remove_square_brackets(text):
    return re.sub('\[2\](\[1\])+', '[2]', text)

pattern_found_note1 = re.compile('[^]]\[1\]')

# Удаление [2][1]
new_text = remove_square_brackets(text)

# Удаление <предыдущий символ>[1]
while pattern_found_note1.search(new_text):
    new_text = pattern_found_note1.sub('', new_text)

# Удаление [2][1]
new_text = remove_square_brackets(new_text)
print(new_text)
```

Или так:

```
...

new_text = text

while True:
    new_text = remove_square_brackets(new_text)
    new_text = pattern_found_note1.sub('', new_text)
    new_text = remove_square_brackets(new_text)
    
    if '[1]' not in new_text:
        break

print(new_text)
```

Консоль:

```
Если здоровье  [2] — истинный сии[2]мвол вободы, то спорт — истинный символ здоровья
```

Answer (score 2):

Без цикла вы вряд ли обойдётесь - иначе не поймаете символы перед множественными `[1]`.

Я бы сделал так:

```
import re

a = "Если здоровье  [2][1] — истинный сии[2]ии[1][1][1]мвол с[1]вободы, тоooo[1][1][1] спорт — истинный симвв[1]оo[1]л здоровья"

b = re.sub(r'(\[2\][^\[1\]]*)\[1\]', lambda x: x.group(1), a)

while True:
    b = re.sub(r'[^\[1\]]\[1\]', '', b)
    if not(re.search(r'\[1\]', b)):
        break

print(b)
```

На выходе:

```
Если здоровье  [2] — истинный сии[2]мвол вободы, то спорт — истинный символ здоровья
```

Comment: где то читал но не могу найти где) писали вроде как regex должен обходить строку циклично (надо указать какой то параметр ) и пока будут совпадения он должен применять одно и тоже правило.